# Better way to detect when a variable != undefined when async request is sent

Tags: javascript, jquery, asynchronous, jquery-deferred

Given the following:

```
var doThings = (function ($, window, document) { 
  var someScopedVariable = undefined,
      methods,
      _status;

  methods = { 
    init: function () { 
      _status.getStatus.call(this);

      // Do something with the 'someScopedVariable'
    }
  };

  // Local method
  _status = { 
    getStatus: function () { 
      // Runs a webservice call to populate the 'someScopedVariable'

      if (someScopedVariable === undefined) { 
        _status.setStatus.call(this);
      }

      return someScopedVariable;

    },
    setStatus: function () { 
      $.ajax({
           url: "someWebservice",
           success: function(results){
              someScopedVariable = results;
           }
         });
    }
  };

  return methods;

} (jQuery, window, document));
```

The issue is clear, this is an async situation were I would like to wait until `someScopedVariable` is not undefined, then continue.

I thought of using jQuery's .when() -> .done() deferred call but I cant seem to get it to work.  I've also thought of doing a loop that would just check to see if its defined yet but that doesnt seem elegant.

Possible option 1:

```
$.when(_status.getStatus.call(this)).done(function () {
        return someScopedVariable; 
});
```

Possible option 2 (Terrible option):

```
_status.getStatus.call(this)

var i = 0;
do {
  i++;
} while (formStatusObject !== undefined);

return formStatusObject;
```

**UPDATE:** 
I believe I stripped out too much of the logic in order to explain it so I added back in some.  The goal of this was to create an accessor to this data.

Comment: What exactly is the internals of getStatus? If it's an AJAX call or something asynchronous you should use callbacks. Blocking - like in option 2 - is a terrible idea that should be avoided.

Comment: Your code looks over-complicated, this might just be because you've stripped out so much but difficult to tell without knowing it's purpose. As mentioned, callbacks are the way forward here, an infinite loop in Javascript will not work well.

Comment: I agree 100% blocking is a terrible idea. I am making an ajax call... Let me update with more specific code...

Comment: Actually the infinite loop will not function at all, because formStatusObject will never change as long as the program does not return to the browsers event loop.

Comment: @Daniel That is correct :) which is why I said that approach is terrible. I was adding that as a "This is what I'd like to do" type thing not this is what I should do. It got misunderstood

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest to wait for the complete / success event of an ajax call.

```
  methods = { 
    init: function () { 
      _status.getStatus.call(this);
    },
    continueInit: function( data ) {
      // populate 'someScopedVariable' from data and continue init
    }
  };

  _status = { 
    getStatus: function () { 
      $.post('webservice.url', continueInit );
    }
  };
```

Comment: or `getStatus.call(this, f)` & `getStatus: function(cb) {`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot block using an infite loop to wait for the async request to finish since your JavaScript is most likely running in a single thread.  The JavaScript engine will wait for your script to finish before it tries to call the async callback that would change the variable you are watching in the loop.  Hence, a deadlock occurrs.

The only way to go is using callback functions throughout, as in your second option.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other answer about using a callback if possible.  If for some reason you need to block and wait for a response, don't use the looping approach, that's about the worst possible way to do that.  The most straightforward would be use set `async:false` in your ajax call.

See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

> async - Boolean Default: true By default,
>   all requests are sent asynchronously
>   (i.e. this is set to true by default).
>   If you need synchronous requests, set
>   this option to false. Cross-domain
>   requests and dataType: "jsonp"
>   requests do not support synchronous
>   operation. Note that synchronous
>   requests may temporarily lock the
>   browser, disabling any actions while
>   the request is active.

Comment: Don't do sync ajax calls, if you do not know exactly what you are doing. Chances are, you will lock your program from responding for several seconds.

Comment: You will lock your program for however long it takes for the response.  This is in rare situations desired.